# What is correct: We will be happy to answer(ing)

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

> - We will be happy to *answer* your questions.
> - We will be happy to *answering* your questions.

Comment: Only the first.

Comment: I always try not to ask off-topic questions. Could you specify why you consider this question to be off-topic? It seems to be a legitimate question to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's either "We will be happy to answer your questions.", meaning something like, "We'd like to answer whatever your questions may be, with pleasure."

Or, probably what you meant the other way around is, "We will be happy, answering your questions."